# .CORE xUnit Test HttpContext.Session

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, httpcontext

I Test Api Controller by xUnit.
In test method, I Need to set some variable like `LoginUser` on `HttpContext.Session` **and get it in Tested Controller**.

My Controller:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("SomeTestedApi")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> SomeTestedApi(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var sessionUser = HttpContext.Session.Get<LoginUser>("loginUser");
        }
    }
```

My xUnit Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ChangeMySupplierTest()
    {
        try
        {
            LoginUser loginUser = await login();
            _httpContext.Session.Set("loginUser", loginUser);
            var request = "/api/SomeTestedApi/?id=5";
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(request);
            Assert.Equal(response.ReasonPhrase, "OK");

        }
    }
```

If Controller called through a real `HTTP request`, It is called after the `LoginController` has been executed. In that case the `SessionContext.Session` object has already received a value.

But When called through the test, is not really keeping the `HttpContext.Session`, so I get `NULL`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem? Not seeing a problem statement. *Is it possible?* what happens when you try it?

Comment: I'll talk more.

Comment: Is this an integration test or unit test? Uncertain based on provided code.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what you need, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi this is Integration Test. I'll try to explain the question a little further